# Mongoose updateMany with aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB supports updates with aggregation pipelines (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).
Here is sample query(https://mongoplayground.net/p/i7A4YoIhyS5).
The update function takes an array (the pipeline) as the second argument.

In Mongoose however, it turns out you can pass only an object (by the docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany, also I have tried myself and array is not supported). Are there any ways to use Updates with aggregation pipelines in Mongoose?

Comment: Please add sample data with query if possible https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Please, check, edited and added a link to mongoplayground. Thanks.

Comment: Can  you please add the expected output details ?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar In there (with native MongoDB) it works as expected. The problem is with Mongoose, if you check the link I shared to Mongoose docs, it says it only accepts an object. So, when I run the same query in Mongoose, it is not updating the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose has not implemented a convenience wrapper for that just yet.

However, [Model.collection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-collection) provides read-only access to the underlying collection object from the native driver, including its methods.

Instead of `Model.updateMany()`, try using `Model.collection.updateMany()`, which should use the syntax described for the MongoDB Node.JS driver

**Edit**

Ugly demo code using Mongoose 5.12 and MongoDB 4.2:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ test:String });

const testModel = mongoose.model('testModel',testSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

async function main() {
    const doc = new testModel({test:"testString"});
    await doc.save();
    const result = await testModel.collection.updateMany({},[{$set:{updated:{$concat:["$test",{$toString:"$_id"}]}}}]);
    console.log("matchedCount:",result.matchedCount);
    console.log("modifiedCount:",result.modifiedCount);
    const newdoc = await testModel.findOne({});
    console.log(newdoc);
    process.exit();
}

main();
```

Output from the above:

```
matchedCount: 1
modifiedCount: 1
{
  _id: 606945d4d5a5d9bec9038a59,
  test: 'testString',
  __v: 0,
  updated: 'testString606945d4d5a5d9bec9038a59'
}
```

Comment: I have checked `Model.collection.updateMany()`. My IDE routed me to its docs (https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/collection.html#updatemany). Turns out it directly uses the method provided by the MongoDB Node.js driver. As you can see there, array parameter is not supported either (only Document). So, still, I cannot use the feature.

Comment: You need to be using MongoDB 4.2 or higher to use pipelines with update.

Comment: Yeap, I am using MongoDB version 4.4.1.