# MongoDB: Access current value of document when adding element to array via $push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulkupdate

I have collection `MyCollection` which basically consists of its `_id` and a string called `comment`.
This collection should be bulk-updatable.

That's done like this:

```
   for (const obj of inputObjects) {
      bulkObjectsToWrite.push({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { _id: obj._id },
          update: {
            $set: {
              comment: obj.comment
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
    await MyCollection.bulkWrite(bulkObjectsToWrite)
```

So far so good.

However, now the requirement is, that a `commentHistory` should be added which should look like `[{"oldValue": "oldValueOfComment", "newValue": "newValueOfComment"}, ...]`

I know I need to use `$push` for adding a new object to the `commentHistory` array. But how do I access the `comment` of the document updated right now, i.e. its current value?

I've tried

```
$push: {
              commentHistory: {
                newValue: obj.comment,
                oldValue: '$comment',
              },
},
```

but to no avail. The string `$comment` is added hard-coded, instead of the field being accessed.

(Using Mongoose 5.12.10 and Mongo 4.4.18)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [update with aggregate pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```
db.collection.update({
  "key": 1
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "comment": "New",
      "commentHistory": {
        "$concatArrays": [    //concatenate existing history array with new array entry
          "$commentHistory",
          [
            {
              "newValue": "New",
              "oldValue": "$comment"  //referencing the existing value
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2ytPh4rYI5X)

Comment: Thansk! But do you happen to know how to do that in Mongoose? According to this answer and its comments things seem not that easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66922686/2710714

Comment: Oh, i thought you can simply replace your query with this. No, I don't know if this works with Mongoose.